# I cannot add Centos 7 repository to install FFMPEG

Tags: linux, centos7, yum, rpm, ffmpeg

When trying to use this command to add ffmpeg repository in Centos 7, I tried to add the repository using this command:

```
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

After several seconds, this error is shown:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Cannot open: https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is the output of `wget https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: It cannot connect. By using ping, server download1.rpmfusion.org is not responding. However, if I do a ping from my PC, it is actually responding. Which may be the reason why from the server that machine cannot be contacted? Is there a difference if I download that RPM from my PC and then upload it to the server? will I lose updates if I do that way?

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to install a package from a URL is `yum install`, not `yum localinstall`. The latter is a deprecated command for installing a package from the local filesystem (which now can also be done with `yum install`).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

yum install epel-release.noarch -y

sudo rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro

sudo rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

yum install -y ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel

Above repo is for Centos-7 for Minor all release.

For Centos 6 Use the following repo:

sudo rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm